# How to retrieve the table values form MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql like this:

```
Id     Name    course_type  module
-----------------------------------
1      php      E           scorm
2      java     E           test
3      php      C           test
4      php      C           scorm
```

I want to retrieve the column `course_type` which has `Name = 'Php'` and `module ='Scorm'`.

For this I am using the following query:

```
$sql= "select * from course where course_id='".$cou."' and module_name ='scorm' ";
$rete = mysql_query($sql);

foreach($rete as $reti) {
    $co_ty =$reti->course_type;
}
```

If I print the `$co_ty` means it display the EC.

What I want is if the `course_type` is E means the output will be E-learn, and  if the `course_type` is C means the output will be Class.

But if the `course_type` is both 'E' and 'C' for the same Name 'Php' and module 'Scorm' means the Output will be 'Both'

How to do that? For this I am trying this code:

```
if($co_ty == 'E') {
    echo 'E-Learning';
} else if ($co_ty=='C') {
    echo 'Classroom';
}
else {
    echo 'Both';
}
```

But the result will be E-learn only.

I don't know how to get this value. Please anyone help me

Comment: Where do you put your `if` code?

Comment: If you want to retrieve column `which contain the Name` then why in your query there's a `course_id='".$cou."'`?

Comment: In my form i have select option in that the Name will be display. i select a name and click submit means that time the records want to display. for that i pass the variable $cou

Answer (score 0):

the problem for ur code is that You are checking in else if condition.
The result is an array, so it find E at first and print only E-Learning and then it leave the execution of the else condition.

You should try this code... hope it helps...

```
if($co_ty == 'E'){
    echo 'E-Learning';
    } if($co_ty=='C'){
    echo 'Classroom';
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. If i do like your way means, in that time if the course_type having C or E  with two(or more) equal records means it having problem . can you please help me

Comment: It will print E-learning And Classroom, when it gets the same.

Comment: You can also check with logical OR instead of else if condition, this if($co_ty=="E" || $co_ty=="C"){ }

Comment: cannot get the proper result

Comment: Do You Only Want to print E-Learning or Classroom Once

Comment: No actually if the course having 3 records with the module scorm . in this all records are E means print E-Learn, if all the records are C means print Course. If the records having both means print Both

Answer (score 0):

```
Try changing your code as below:

$sql= "select * from course where course_id='".$cou."' and module_name ='scorm' ";

$rete  = mysql_query($sql);
$co_ty = '';

foreach($rete as $reti)
{
   $co_ty .=$reti->course_type;
} 

if($co_ty == 'E')
{
    echo 'E-Learning';
}
else if($co_ty=='C')
{
    echo 'Classroom';
}
else`enter code here`
{
    echo 'Both';
}
```

Comment: can't get the correct value . if the course_type is E and the name and module is same . totallay i have 3 records ( for example ) means it will print both only